# Gstreamer gst_event_new_seek start and stop position

Tags: c, gstreamer

I feel I am missing something obvious, so I apologize in advance.

I am going through the GStreamer [Basic tutorial 13: Playback speed](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/playback-speed.html). Although I think I grasp it, I am confused by the following sentence (my bold) in the explanation of the send_seek_event code:

> The Seek Event is created with gst_event_new_seek(). Its parameters
>   are, basically, the new rate, the new start position and the new stop
>   position. Regardless of the playback direction, **the start position
>   must be smaller than the stop position**, so the two playback directions
>   are treated differently.

However, (in the same tutorial) the code for creating the event that will change the playback rate:

```
  /* Obtain the current position, needed for the seek event */
  if (!gst_element_query_position (data->pipeline, GST_FORMAT_TIME, &position)) {
    g_printerr ("Unable to retrieve current position.\n");
    return;
  }

  /* Create the seek event */
  if (data->rate > 0) {
    seek_event = gst_event_new_seek (data->rate, GST_FORMAT_TIME, GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH | GST_SEEK_FLAG_ACCURATE,
        GST_SEEK_TYPE_SET, position, GST_SEEK_TYPE_NONE, 0);
  } else {
    seek_event = gst_event_new_seek (data->rate, GST_FORMAT_TIME, GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH | GST_SEEK_FLAG_ACCURATE,
        GST_SEEK_TYPE_SET, 0, GST_SEEK_TYPE_SET, position);
  }
```

In the code:

- for rate > 0 (playing forward), start_position is position (>0) and stop_position is 0
- for rate < 0 (playing backwards), start_position is 0 and stop_position is position (>0)

Is it a typo in the tutorial? Am I missing something really obvious?

Answer (score 0):

When the rate < 0, playback is start from stop_position and go to start_position.
So, start position is smaller than the stop position.

Comment: Yes, in that case start_position=0 < stop_position=position. However, the problem is for rate > 0. When rate>0, start_position=position and stop_position=0. As position is >0, it appears not to comply the start_position<stop_position asert. ?

Answer (score 0):

It's a typo. It's:

```
seek_event =
    gst_event_new_seek (data->rate, GST_FORMAT_TIME,
    GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH | GST_SEEK_FLAG_ACCURATE, GST_SEEK_TYPE_SET,
    position, GST_SEEK_TYPE_END, 0);
```

It's "0 from the end".

Look here: https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-docs/blob/master/examples/tutorials/basic-tutorial-13.c#L30